# Unchecking "Scale symbols when reference layer set" by default in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, layers, symbology, scale

In Layer Properties > Display, the "Scale symbols when a reference layer is set" is checked by default, and 90% of the time I don't want/need the symbols scaled.

Is there any way to change the default setting so this box is unchecked when a new layer is added?

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.1.

Comment: I used to have a small Add-In that would un-check that option for layers selected in the ToC.  It didn't do it by default, but was a quick way to change it once they were added

Comment: @Midavalo was that an ArcMap (ArcObjects) AddIn or a Python AddIn?

Comment: @PolyGeo it was an ArcObjects Add-In I wrote years ago.  I think I still have it somewhere - I'll find it after the weekend when i'm back in the office

Comment: Why did you set a reference scale if you dont need to scale symbols ?

Answer (score 1):

There are two places that I have looked for this option:

- Customize | ArcMap Options
- C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\Utilities\AdvancedArcMapSettings.exe

It does not seem to be configurable using either.

Consequently, I think you will need to consider submitting/supporting an [ArcGIS Idea](https://geonet.esri.com/community/arcgis-ideas).